# SSIS event handler script task

Tags: ssis

i have a package that has several event handlers that execute a script task on failure when the package fails.. Problem is its generating a email that i have NO IDEA how.. When the package fails it executes a stored procedure that grabs the email distribution list from a SQL table and sends an email. However one email is being sent out to ppl who are not with the company and ive been told twice to change the DL list.. I checked the SQL table and the people that are getting the email are not listed any where in the distribution list.. Is there any way to search anywhere in the package to find out how the email is being generated. Ive spent hours and hours going through the scrip tasks and the code is no where to be found

Answer (score 2):

You can use the package explorer (to the right of the event handler tab) to navigate through the entire package and look at the event handlers for every executable.  It's possible that there are multiple event handlers, one at the package level and maybe one defined on a particular task, which is hardcoded with email addresses.

You can also, right click on the package in the solution explorer and select View Code.  This will open the package in xml, which you can then use ctrl+F to find a certain string.

**Advice Section**

While you didn't ask for it, please let me add a few words of guidance.  Event handlers are evil for this very reason.  They are a hidden GOTO that you are lucky to notice at all, even if you've developed the package in the first place.

If event handling is required, use the precedence constraints in the control flow.  Throw everything in a container, connect it to the script task and define the constraint to trigger on failure.

To go one step further, keep your emails out of your ssis packages.  Use SQL agent or whatever scheduler you are using to post messages about failures.